# Download remote JSX file to localStorage in react-native

Tags: android, local-storage, react-native, remote-access, reactjs

I am new in React-Native and I want to ask you if is possible to download JSX file like template of something, which is located on remote server and use this JSX template to show new View on my built react-native android app?
If it is possible, could you write me how?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle file needs to be complete. There is no way at this time to split your bundle into multiple files, which would negate the purpose of the packager.

You may want to look into something like CodePush's RN integration which allows you to download bundle files OTA: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push

Comment: Thank you, it's good idea but it is not what I am searching for. I try to once more explain it.    So I want to make an app in RN which will contain login form. This form will be linked with web app where are users registered in.    Every user has one of four roles. If user log in to my android app, specific template (or view) according to user role will be every time downloaded and showed like new activity.                     So my problem is that I don't know if is possible to download some file, save it to local storage and work with it in my app.  Thank you for your next solution.